# SQL Server Management Studio not opening files

Tags: ssms, sql-server-express

I just installed Microsoft SQL Server Express and Management Studio, the Management Studio opens but will not open files. I am getting the following message when I try to open a SQL file:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir8Ia.png)

Any help would be so much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is the known issue in SSMS 18.0 preview 6 and before.

Double-clicking on a .sql file launches SSMS, but does not open the actual script.

As workarounds, please drag and drop the .sql file onto the SSMS editor.

If it is possible, you can use the SSMS 17.9.1 instead. Here is the download link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that you're asking to grab something from an unaccessable directory. I'm not too sure, try reinstalling ssms if possible and reinstall sql express and see what it does